# Вывод информации в текстовое поле

Tags: c++, qt, form

Вообщем у меня есть qt форма. На ней есть текстовое поле, куда я хочу выводит различную информацию. Также на этой форме есть кнопка, которая создает объект определенного класса и вызывает его методы. В методах этого класса я хотел бы иметь механизм, который позволял бы мне выводит информацию в текстовое поле формы на этапе исполнения кода (а не через переменную, которая бы сохраняла информацию, а затем в классе формы вызвать метод, который бы получил значения этой переменной и записал в текстовое поле).
Также в вызывающих методах класса могут создаваться еще объекты, в методах которых, я бы также хотел получить доступ к текстовому полю.

Как это можно сделать?

В качестве решения придумал создавать объект класса формы, где нужен вывод, но тогда может получиться куча создаваемых объектов внутри самого себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте технологию сигнал-слот ([Сигналы и слоты в Qt](http://habrahabr.ru/post/50812/))

Comment: сделал для класса, объект которого создает кнопка.
Чтобы сделать для классов, объекты которых создаются в моем классе, нужно получается создать цепочку сигналов и слотов?!

Comment: вариант №1 - цепочка сигнал-слотов
вариант №2 - создать прокси-класс для посылки сигналов. Т.е. не нужно будет прокидывать сигнал из самого вложенного класса наверх. Достаточно будет подключить сигнал этого класса на прокси, а сигнал прокси - на форму

Comment: спасибо, думаю 2 вариант лучше подойдет мне.